# Ошибка segmentation fault в printf

Tags: c

Что тут не верно? Никак не могу понять! Мне выбивает "segmentation fault" :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int checkNum(int);

int main() {
    int i;
    int num;

    for (i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        num=1000;
        if (checkNum(num) == 1) printf(num);
    }
}

int checkNum(int myNum) {
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", num)`?

Comment: @VladD, а что это даст?

Comment: Не будет падать?

Comment: Вам пора осваивать отладчик...

Comment: Этот код вообще компилировался так?

Comment: @VladD, закиньте в ответ и объясните почему не падает, пожалуйста.

Comment: @LEQADA: Для древних K&R-компилфторов вполне может быть и warning.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я вообще на Java пишу, это так, помощь другу.

Comment: @bukashka101: окей, сейчас

Comment: @bukashka101 тогда пускай друг освоит отладчик. Программы сложнее Hello World имеют тенденцию работать не как задумано и без отладчика ваш друг вас задолбает.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, эту программу я сам писал (кроме библиотек) от начала до конца (без знания Си и с гуглом).

Comment: Господа, а почему все (@VladD и @Vlad from Moscow) на вопрос ответили, а заголовок оставили бесполезным для потомков? =( Я его исправил, проверьте, если чё не так, а то я с `С` не дружу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Угу, спасибо, всё правильно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) получает на вход первым аргументом строку с форматом, который описывает, что именно надо вывести. Если вместо строки написать число, современный компилятор должен либо не откомпилировать, либо по крайней мере вывести предупреждение о несоответствии вызова и сигнатуры. В вашем случае компилятор преобразовал число 1000 к указателю (а строка в C есть не что иное как указатель на первый символ), программа попыталась получить доступ по такому указателю, что, конечно, завершилось вылетом.

Правильный вызов — `printf("%d\n", num)`.

Форматная строка `"%d\n"` означает следующее:

`%d` — аргумент должен быть целым числом, вывести его
`\n` — вывести перевод строки (его можно и выбросить)

---

Действительно, `printf` с неправильным аргументом компилируется, хоть и с предупреждением, в C, но не в C++. Например, такой файл:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    num = 1000;
    printf(num);
}
```

обрабатывается gcc 4.9.3 следующим образом в режиме C:

```
[VladD@Kenga] [23:41:59] [~/c++]
{0,509}$> gcc printf_decl.c -o printf_decl && ./printf_decl
printf_decl.c: In function 'main':  
printf_decl.c:8:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer
from integer without a cast
    printf(num);
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from printf_decl.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:181:5: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
 int _EXFUN(printf, (const char *__restrict, ...)
     ^
```

... что заканчивается законным сегфолтом:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

А в режиме C++ просто не компилируется:

```
[VladD@Kenga] [23:42:07] [~/c++]
{0,510}$> gcc -x c++ printf_decl.c -o printf_decl && ./printf_decl
printf_decl.c: In function 'int main()':
printf_decl.c:8:15: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
     printf(num);
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from printf_decl.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:181:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'int printf(const char*, ...)'
 int _EXFUN(printf, (const char *__restrict, ...)
     ^
```

Answer (score 6):

Проблема в неверном использовании функции `printf`

```
printf(num);
```

Ее первый параметр должен иметь тип `const char *`. Вы же указали тип объект типа `int`, который функция интерпретирует как адрес.

Вот как выглядит объявление этой функции

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

Я думаю, вы имеете в виду

```
printf( "%d ", num );
```

или

```
printf( "%d\n", num );
```

В зависимости от вашего вкуса.:)

Имейте в виду, что согласно стандарту C функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
```

Раздел *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup* стандарта C

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Не могли бы показать это место в стандарте (насчёт функции main)? Я поискал - не смог найти.

Comment: @LEQADA Смотрите мой ответ. Я дописал его.

Comment: with no parameters не означает `void`

Comment: И по хорошему main должна возвращать число - код завершения программы.
Если всё нормально, то 0.

Comment: @sercxjo Она и возвращает 0.:)

Comment: @LEQADA Там специально показано, как она должна объявляться. После слов "with no parameters:" стоит двоеточие и определение функции..

Comment: Где? Что-то не вижу оператора `return`

Comment: @sercxjo Вы же сказали "по-хорошему", не так ли? Вот она "по-хорошему" без всяких напоминаний возвращает 0.:)

Comment: Как сейчас она ничего не возвращает, вернее "мусор".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, видите, как хорошо? Мы нашли нестыковку в стандарте :)

Comment: @sercxjo Она возвращает 0, если вы сами не вставили предложение с return.

Comment: @LEQADA Да? А я даже не знал...:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, кстати, там и int может быть опущен. Было бы здорово, если бы вы пролили свет на эту часть со ссылками на стандарт.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow попробуйте, у меня данная программа (исправленная чтобы работала) возвращает 5, т.е. "мусор"

Comment: @sercxjo, Влад прав. По стандарту C99 без `return` возвращается 0.

Comment: @sercxjo Это либо что-то вы делаете неправильно, либо ваш компилятор имеет баг.

Comment: Не обязательно баг. Компилятор может быть старым.

Comment: @LEQADA Вообще-то фраза из стандарта начинается со слов "It shall be defined with a return type of int"

Comment: Точно, включил std=c99 - стала возвращать 0

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, с std=c99 тоже начал ругаться на объявление без int.

Comment: @LEQADA а у меня без типа - warning и возвращает 0, а если void main - без ошибок, но возвращает мусор

Comment: Надеюсь, кто-нибудь прольёт на это свет.